# Academic Licence on Microsoft Events

Tags: dreamspark

On november 15 there is a Microsoft Hackathon in Kortrijk (Belgium) where I want to compete with a friend. However, my licence of Visual Studio is a licence which I got from Dreamspark Premium.

To avoid problems november 15 I want to be sure I can use my dreamspark licence on the hackathon. Is there anyone who knows for sure its allowed (by being a lawyer or experienced)

Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: Your license is valid until you are no longer eligible to download the software which is normally 24 months after you "purchase" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to help but you did not mention the **end of the licence date**?

For indepth-details for MS licence subscriptions, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020421/detecting-visual-studio-license-type-distribution-channel). Also this [QA topic suggests](https://superuser.com/questions/252749/dreamspark-is-really-giving-me-free-software?rq=1) it is free.

On another note, do you think it you are much less competitive by using the free **Visual Studio (2012) Express Editions**.The IDE is pretty similar, as are the shortcuts. Am I correct in the assumption that this event is a few-hours long Hackathon ?

In fact, you may just as well use MonoDevelop and probably still be highly competitive based on other merits than your proficiency in a given IDE.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the end of licence date. According to dreamspark itself it expires february 2015.